# Creating a basic Table with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a bit confused how to create tables with Flask-SQLAlchemy -- the examples I've found elsewhere seem to be using different a different initialization (e.g., using Base) than the one below.

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

# Define models
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    favcolor = db.Column(db.String(255)) #FAVS
    favshape = db.Column(db.String(255)) #FAVS
    favflower = db.Column(db.String(255)) #FAVS
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __str__(self):
            return '<User id=%s email=%s>' % (self.id, self.email)
```

Basically, let's say I want to have all the of the `fav` variables (`favcolor`, `favshape`, and `favflower`) in a separate table of its own, called `favorites`.

How can I make sure that I can access these favorite using the primary_key?

Seems basic! Hopefully there's an easy way to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a 'UserFavorites' models that has a one-to-one relationship to a user.

```
class UserFavorites(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)
    color = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, default='')
    shape = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, default='')
    flower = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, default='')

    user = db.relationship(User, backref=db.backref('favorites', uselist=False))
```

Create a UserFavorites instance while creating a User instance.

```
user = User(email='example@example.com', favorites=UserFavorites(color='green'))
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()

user = User.query.filter(
    User.email == 'example@example.com'
).options(
    db.joinedload(User.favorites)
).one()
print user.favorites.color
```

You can join across this relationship to query User about it's Favorites.

```
likes_green = User.query.join(User.favorites).filter(
    UserFavorites.color == 'green'
).all()
print [u.email for u in likes_green]
```